# If pictures are Haram, what about pictures of Mecca, Ka'ba etc ? Are they haram too?

Tags: halal-haram

If pictures images areally Haram , then is it permissible to keep pictures of Islamic Holy Sites  ?

Comment: According to that question, it is permissible to have pictures without living beings in it. But in this context,  the Ka'ba is always surrounded by people.

Comment: You should clarify in your question that you are talking about 'photographs' and those which would include pilgrims in it. Note that many scholars view photographs to be different matter from images which are mentioned in ahadith and consider them permissible based on analogy with mirrors.

Comment: I don't know of any consensus among scholars saying that photographys are haram. And pictures of this kind are even less doubtfull.